# How to delete Devise table to run 'rake db:migrate'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am adding devise to my web application in Rails 3.2.12. I ran a successful `$ rails generate devise:install` and `$ rails generate devise User`.

This is what I get when I run `$ rake routes`:

```
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
             user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
            user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                          PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
        user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                          PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                     root        /                              pages#home
                    about GET    /about(.:format)               pages#about
```

When I attempt to run `rake db:migrate`, I get the following **error**:

```
 ==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
 -- create_table(:users)
 rake aborted!
 An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

 SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY     KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "encrypted_password"    varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "reset_password_token" varchar(255), "reset_password_sent_at"    datetime, "remember_created_at" datetime, "sign_in_count" integer DEFAULT 0, "current_sign_in_at"    datetime, "last_sign_in_at" datetime, "current_sign_in_ip" varchar(255), "last_sign_in_ip"    varchar(255), "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)   /Users/andyHuynh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in    `initialize'
```

It's telling me I have a 'users' table already. If this is the case, where is this sql table? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at your previous migrations to see if there was one that created a `users` table. If so, maybe delete that migration. In any case, I'd go into your `rails dbconsole` and manually drop the `users` table, then run `rake db:migrate` again.

Comment: I dropped the users table in the dbconsole and it worked! You rock @jason

Comment: I would still check old migrations. You'd hate to be in a situation where you can't go back and run all your migrations over because you have multiple migrations trying to create the same table.

Comment: I have one file in my migrations folder. Is that the file you are referring to? What should I be looking at in particular?

Comment: If your one migration file is the Devise one, then you should be good. If your one file is one *additional* user migration file, I'd say delete that migration.